# How to implement native ads of google admob in ionic capacitorjs

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, capacitor

I'm making an app using the ionic framework.

I wanted to implement native ads of google admob for advertising revenue.
I was able to get the information from native ads and show it to you, but I couldn't find a way to tap this ad.
I want to know if there is a good way.

Using the onNativeAdLoaded method, advertising information (Body, HeadLine, CTA,icon) can be called from Capacitor in a way that creates NativeAd by creating Capacitor Plugin by itself. But since pressing this ad is in Android's ad view itself, I couldn't find a way to tap this ad.

```
adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, adUnitId)
      .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd nativeAd) {
          nanativeAd = nativeAd;
          JSObject nativeAdInfo = new JSObject();

          nativeAdInfo.put("adBody", nativeAd.getBody());
          nativeAdInfo.put("adHeadline", nativeAd.getHeadline());
          nativeAdInfo.put("adAction", nativeAd.getCallToAction());
          NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();
          NativeAd.AdChoicesInfo adChoicesInfo = nativeAd.getAdChoicesInfo();
          if(icon != null) {
            nativeAdInfo.put("adImage", icon.getUri().toString());
          }
          if(adChoicesInfo != null) {
            adUrl = adChoicesInfo.getText().toString();
          }
          call.resolve(nativeAdInfo);
        }
      })
```

```
export interface EchoPlugin {
    loadNativeAd(options: { adUnitId: string }): Promise<{ adBody: string; adHeadline: string; adAction: string; adImage: string, adUrl: string }>;
    launchAd(): Promise<void>;
    addListener(eventName: string, listenerFunc: (...args: any[]) => void): PluginListenerHandle;
}
```